# How can I best optimize a loop that will loop over a billion times?

Tags: java, loops, optimization

Say I want to go through a loop a billion times how could I optimize the loop to get my results faster?

As an example:

```
double randompoint;
for(long count =0; count < 1000000000; count++) {
        randompoint = (Math.random() * 1) + 0;  //generate a random point
        if(randompoint <= .75) {
            var++; 
        }
    }
```

I was reading up on vecterization? But I'm not quite sure how to go about it. Any Ideas?

Comment: Vectorization = parallelization?  Designing for concurrency is a large topic, probably not suitable for SO.

Comment: This basically generates a random variable whose value is close to 750 millions. Why not just generate a random deviation (between, let's say, -100,000 and + 100,000), and add it to 750 million?

Comment: Side note. `(Math.random() * 1) + 0` is equivalent with `Math.random()` b/c `(a * 1) + 0 == a`

Comment: Seeing the answer was deleted, there's a high chance that adding parallelism to this will yield worse results due to the overhead of threading it. Generally need a significant amount of work that threading truly shines in this example.

Comment: Parallelism will absolutely give a perfectly linear speedup for this kind of code. The deleted answer just did it in a convenient but inefficient way

Comment: @zlakad Interesting, I didn't know that. In my actual code I'm letting user set those numbers. I just wanted to use a simple example.

Comment: Depends how its implemented. The creation of any thread, any threadpool, etc. etc. incurs a significant amount of overhead. If the bottom line is speed I doubt it will ever be faster to thread. Again a code golf life challenge seems fun to figure out the minimal amount of work each thread should have to incur to make this faster.

Comment: @thatotherguy How was the deleted code inefficient?

Comment: @imalogginin  Any use of parallel streams has a significant amount of overhead. Just because its super easy to do does not meant its automatically more performant. The latest Java8 in action has a section dedicated to when you should even consider parallel streams.

Comment: @imalogginin It generated streams full of numbers, applied a transformer to each number, applied a filter function to each result, and finally counted it. This is has a huge overhead over simply iterating.

Comment: @thatotherguy So how would I go about it by just iterating?

Comment: Your best bet would be to use http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-performance/jmh.html and play about with different implementations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Java is cross-platform, you pretty much have to rely on the JIT to vectorize. In your case it can't, since each iteration depends heavily on the previous one (due to how the RNG works).

However, there are two other major ways to improve your computation.

The first is that this work is very amenable to parallelization. The technical term is [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel). This means that multithreading will give a perfectly linear speedup over the number of cores.

The second is that `Math.random()` is written to be multithreading safe, which also means that it's slow because it needs to use atomic operations. This isn't helpful, so we can skip that overhead by using a non-threadsafe RNG.

I haven't written much Java since 1.5, but here's a dumb implementation:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

class Foo implements Runnable {
  private long count;
  private double threshold;
  private long result;

  public Foo(long count, double threshold) {
    this.count = count;
    this.threshold = threshold;
  }

  public void run() {
    ThreadLocalRandom rand = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    for(long l=0; l<count; l++) {
      if(rand.nextDouble() < threshold)
        result++;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    long count = 1000000000;
    double threshold = 0.75;
    int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    long sum = 0;

    List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<Foo>();
    List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    for(int i=0; i<cores; i++) {
      // TODO: account for count%cores!=0
      Foo t = new Foo(count/cores, threshold);
      list.add(t);
      Thread thread = new Thread(t);
      thread.start();
      threads.add(thread);
    }
    for(Thread t : threads) t.join();
    for(Foo f : list) sum += f.result;

    System.out.println(sum);
  }
}
```

You can also optimize and inline the random generator, to avoid going via doubles. Here it is with code taken from the ThreadLocalRandom docs:

```
  public void run() {
    long seed = new Random().nextLong();
    long limit = (long) ((1L<<48) * threshold);

    for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
      seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1);
      if (seed < limit) ++result;
    }
  }
```

However, the best approach is to work smarter, not harder. As the number of events increases, the probability tends towards a normal distribution. This means that for your huge range, you can randomly generate a number with such a distribution and scale it:

```
import java.util.Random;

class StayInSchool {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(coinToss(1000000000, 0.75));
  }
  static long coinToss(long iterations, double threshold) {
    double mean = threshold * iterations;
    double stdDev = Math.sqrt(threshold * (1-threshold) * iterations);

    double p = new Random().nextGaussian();
    return (long) (p*stdDev + mean);
  }
}
```

Here are the timings on my 4 core system (including VM startup) for these approaches:

- Your baseline: 20.9s
- Single threaded ThreadLocalRandom: 6.51s
- Single threaded optimized random: 1.75s
- Multithreaded ThreadLocalRandom: 1.67s
- Multithreaded optimized random: 0.89s
- Generating a gaussian: 0.14s

Comment: `Since Java is cross-platform, you pretty much have to rely on the JIT to vectorize` this seems to imply JITted languages can't support SIMD which is not quite correct. There are some support in C# and Javascript via specific vector types like Mono.Simd Vector4f

Comment: There's no reason to use doubles. The original expression is basically `random.nextDouble() <= .75` which has pretty exactly the same probability as `random.nextInt(4) < 3`. There's a tiny difference, but the OP most probably wanted a probability of 0.75 (which corresponds with `random.nextDouble() < .75` (rather than `<=`).